# Braintree - onReady Not Firing

Tags: braintree

I have the following code which uses the Braintree drop-in but it doesn't look like `onReady` is firing even though the drop-in loads and works just fine.

```
braintree.setup("TOKEN", "dropin", {
  container: "dropin",
  onReady: function(o) {
    console.log("ready");
  }
});
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. Your code looks correct, so please reach out to [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com) so we can further investigate your issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ? I have the same here ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not.

Comment: OnReady callback function working fine with browser environment but not working with cordova application :(
any one can help please

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that can interfere with onReady callback is CSS transition if placed on the iframe. We had this, hard to find, issue when design team placed CSS transition on iframe. Here is the css code that breaks the onReady callback:

```
#dropin iframe {
   transition: all 0s ease 0s !important;
}
```